# Ng2 charts - Animation doesn't work on line chart onInit

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am working with ng2 charts to create dashboard.
When i work with line charts the animation doesn't work onInit but is work when the chart is complete and update data.

A part of my options:

```
animation: {
      animation: true,
      duration: 2500,
}
```

My html:

```
<canvas baseChart height="450" width="1120" [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors" [chartType]="lineChartType"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify animation type in order to overwrite the default behavior, like this:

```
animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true,
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'easeInOutElastic',
    }
```

where:

```
 easing: Easing = 'linear' | 'easeInQuad' | 'easeOutQuad' | 'easeInOutQuad' | 'easeInCubic' | 'easeOutCubic' | 'easeInOutCubic' |
    'easeInQuart' | 'easeOutQuart' | 'easeInOutQuart' | 'easeInQuint' | 'easeOutQuint' | 'easeInOutQuint' | 'easeInSine' | 'easeOutSine' |
    'easeInOutSine' | 'easeInExpo' | 'easeOutExpo' | 'easeInOutExpo' | 'easeInCirc' | 'easeOutCirc' | 'easeInOutCirc' | 'easeInElastic' |
    'easeOutElastic' | 'easeInOutElastic' | 'easeInBack' | 'easeOutBack' | 'easeInOutBack' | 'easeInBounce' | 'easeOutBounce' | 'easeInOutBounce';
```

If you want to triger onComplete() or onProgress(), they could also be defined.